# NetBeans Remote Project fails to save: 550 Could not delete (filename.php.new). No such file or directory

Tags: php, netbeans, ftp, server

I am working on a PHP project using netbeans through a remote directory. 
Suddently, this error started to come up. It has worked fine before.

Output-Remote Log:

```
USER myuser@mydomain.com
331 User myuser@mydomain.com OK. Password required
PASS ******
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
CWD /
250 OK. Current directory is /
PWD
257 "/" is your current location
CWD /application/views
250 OK. Current directory is /application/views
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (68,65,122,150,47,97)
DELE client_registration.php.new
550 Could not delete client_registration.php.new: No such file or directory
QUIT
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
```

It also happens if I try to change other files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something has changed with the FTP configuration on your remote server.

I had the same issue and I've solved it the following way:

The error was caused by an wrong upload path.

So I've accessed the remote server with FileZilla using my FTP-Credetials.
There I could see the path to the file in the FTP-Environment.
In netbeans open the properties of your project and edit the upload directory.

Just enter the path you've seen in the FTP-Client (FileZilla) there.

That worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to occur when it is trying to enter the **"PASSIVE MODE"**. **You need to stop the connection from entering the "PASSIVE MODE"**. By the following steps.

1. Right click on the project
2. Select Properties
3. Select Run Configurations
4. Select Manage
5. Select your_ftp_connection on the left column
6. "Manage remote connection" dialogue box will appear. In that check off the "Passive mode". Then click "OK".

Now it should work !!!